# Alternate form of a seventh order polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Write the function $f(x)=x^7-3x^6+4x^3-2x+5$ in the form $f(x)=(x-k)q(x)+r$ for $k=-2$ and show that $f(k)=r$.
So we have $f(x)=(x+2)q(x)+r$ but what can we do now?
Thanks.

Comment: [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)

Comment: You want to divide (with remainder) one polynomial by another.  Have you considered [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)?  In fact, this is an excellent application of [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).  Are you familiar with either of these?

Comment: $$x^7-3x^6+4x^3-2x+5=x^6\color{red}{(x+2)}-5x^5\color{red}{(x+2)}+10x^4\color{red}{(x+2)}-20x^3\color{red}{(x+2)}+44x^2\color{red}{(x+2)}+88x\color{red}{(x+2)}-176\color{red}{(x+2)}+?$$

Comment: In your last equation, $f(-2)=(-2+2)q(-2)+r=0q(-2)+r=r$

Comment: Thanks for your help.